# Java Tensorflow Serving Prediction Client Too Slow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I have created a `tensorflow` object detection model and served it using `tensorflow` serving. I have created a python client to test the serving model and that takes around 40ms time to receive all the prediction.

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0)  # 60 secs timeout
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print ((t2 - t1).microseconds / 1000)
```

Now, my problem is when I do the same on `java`, it takes way too much time (about 10 times) of 450 to 500ms.

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9000)
        .usePlaintext(true)
        .build();
PredictionServiceGrpc.PredictionServiceBlockingStub stub = PredictionServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

......

Instant pre = Instant.now();
Predict.PredictResponse response = stub.predict(request);
Instant curr = Instant.now();
System.out.println("time " + ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(pre,curr));
```

Comment: Java as a language is very slow initially. It's only after it "warms up" that it becomes very fast. If this was the first gRPC call in your program, I'd easily believe it was as slow as you mention, because then Java wouldn't be "warm." Subsequent calls should be faster, and eventually (after the JIT compiles enough) I'd expect them to be faster than Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was that,

I was sending all the image pixels over the network (which was a bad idea). Now, changing the input to an encoded image made it faster.